# Compute Errors on Fit Parameters In Scipy Curve fit

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Using "scipy.optimize.curve_fit" we can determine the fit parameters for a curve fit on x and y using

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
```

In the documentation for this function, they state that: To compute one standard deviation errors on the parameters use

```
perr = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
```

Here's a link to the documentation I was reading. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

What if I want to compute something more general than simply 1 standard deviation on the errors of the parameters? In particular, what If I'm looking for, say, 2 standard deviations (a 95% confidence interval on the parameters).

To be clear, I'm not looking for a 10 line+ solution.  I already know how to compute these errors in a "hackish" way for a linear function:

```
def get_slope_params(data1, data2):
    x_mean = mean(data1)
    y_mean = mean(data2)
    N = len(data1)

    sum_xy = 0
    for (x, y) in zip(data1, data2):
        sum_xy = sum_xy + x*y

     sum_xsq = 0
    for x in data1:
        sum_xsq = sum_xsq + x*x

    b = (sum_xy-N*x_mean*y_mean)/(sum_xsq-N*x_mean**2)
    a = y_mean - b*x_mean

     return (a,b)

# 95%
def get_slope_params_uncertainties(data1, data2):
    N = len(data1)
    a, b = get_slope_params(data1, data2)
    y_approx = a+b*data1

    s_eps = 0
    for (y, y_app) in zip(data2, y_approx):
        s_eps = s_eps + (y-y_app)**2
    s_eps = np.sqrt(s_eps/(N-2))

    s_x = np.sqrt(cov(data1, data1))

    delta_b = (1/np.sqrt(N-1))*(s_eps/s_x)*sp.stats.t.ppf(1-0.05/2, N-2)
    delta_a = mean(data1)*delta_b

    return delta_a, delta_b
```

What I'd like is a function already implemented entirely by scipy.

Comment: I am afraid that no such function exists in scipy, since the functionalities of `curve_fit` are rather limited. If you do not want to calculate confidence intervals by hand you have the option to use other packages for fitting, for example `lmfit` (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/), which has functionalitites for the calculation of confidence intervals (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/confidence.html).